# How to add search engine using Firefox's address bar?

Tags: firefox, search, address-bar

If I go to a website offering dictionary features, e.g. dictionary.com, I can easily add this search engine to Firefox using the search bar.

[image]

Say that I'm using Firefox without the *search bar*. How can I add a search engine using the *address bar*?

There's no option in the address bar for it as far as I can see; to add this search engine I changed preferences, added the search engine, then removed the search bar again.

Comment: Currently the only apparent way is: 1) expose the search bar; 2) add an engine and pick it as default; 3) hide the search bar. I wonder if that's the way they have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now an option on the page action menu to add a search engine. This is available from Firefox 61 onwards.

[image]

From the [release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/61.0/releasenotes/) of Firefox 61.0:

> Convenient access to more search engines: You can now add search engines to the address bar “Search with” tool from the page action menu when on a webpage that provides an OpenSearch plugin

Comment: Now you just have to right-click on the address bar to see that option.

Answer (score 1):

See the Mozilla article
[Search the web from the address bar](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-web-address-bar) :

> When you type in the address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Return</kbd>, Firefox takes you to search results
>   **using the search provider selected in the search bar**.

You may also use smart keyword as described in
[How to search IMDB, Wikipedia and more from the address bar](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-search-from-address-bar).

Comment: I want to add a search engine (to the list of search engines already in Firefox). The search bar allows us to easily do this (see image in question) but not the address bar. // What I want to know is if there is an easier way to add a new search engine without having to first show the search bar, then adding the search engine, and finally hiding the search bar again.

Comment: @Daniel , based upon the official Mozilla references that Harrymc cited, I'm afraid that the simple answer is "no."  That being said, I would assume that you wouldn't be adding search engines *too* often, so hopefully the minor inconvenience of utilizing this workaround is rather rare.

Comment: You may use the smart keyword mechanism : For example define "q" as the keyword for the search engine, then query by "q my-query" in the address bar.